# Twitter Bootstrap - Vertically align input with label inside control-group

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label ">Date of purchase as detailed on your receipt</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
            <select name="invoice_date" value="2013-06-28" required="required">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" class="btn info btn-primary" data-help="invoice_date">i</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried a few solutions and one kind of worked using position absolute, but this affected other areas of bootstrap in particular when it gets responsive.

http://jsfiddle.net/tGZLd/

I am trying to get the input to line up with the center of the label that has been pushed over multiple lines but in the best practice of bootstrap.

Or should I simply give up and force it to display a full width label with the input underneath?

Any insight would be great, thanks!

Comment: I added `margin-top: 10px` to `div.input-append` and that seems to make it look nice but not sure if that's what you're going for. Play around with margins and padding rather than positioning so that other inputs you add will also be influenced by those changes. Let me know how that goes

Comment: I just added css for the `select` and the `button` tags to `style="vertical-align:text-top"`. Is that what you are looking for? Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EwD6Z/

Comment: @aug That is a stop gap solution and could work if I set multiple styles but I was looking for something more dynamic.

Comment: @jlars62 That is quite a good solution for neatening things up and may be a possible solution however I was looking to vertical align it, so say you had a label with 3 lines that the input would remain vertically centered to the label.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about overriding Bootstrap's styles and using `display:inline-block;` instead of floats for the positioning, then you can use `vertical-align` to center the label:

```
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
.form-horizontal .controls {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tGZLd/1/)**

Comment: I just tested this and although I have only done light testing it was responsive and it has actually solved another issue I was experiencing with the responsive aspects of the forms with Bootstrap. This is so simple too can't believe I missed it, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Add a class to the input-append then apply a margin to that.

```
    <div class="input-append spacedTop">
```

Then add the CSS

```
    .spacedTop { margin-top:10px; }
```

If you don't do an extra class it will margin any other input-appends you use throughout your site.

Comment: As mentioned above this would be a solution but when labels begin spanning more lines then it is not a dynamic enough solution, thanks for the idea though.