# How to vertically align long label in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have got a long label next to my input and it is not vertically aligned.

Is there some option to solve it [like it was in Bootstrap 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17846073/1092627), please?

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Labdas kjas kljas dlkjasd lksjd     el1</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Input1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input2" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Label2</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="input2" placeholder="Input2">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

not very cleanly... you would need to add an override class to the long label, such as `multiline` and then add a definition for that class like so

```
.control-label.multiline
{
    padding-top:0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I'm afraid that I cannot do that because my form is automatically rendered by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, that may or may not work based on your implementation.
I've used it to handle some cases where I needed the 'col' classes to take up full height of their rows. Essentially it's telling the browser to interpret it as a table. That should allow you to vertically align the label to the middle.

I put it in a media query because smaller than that it stacks for me.

```
/* addition for displaying bits as tables to gain cell features */
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .table-display{display:table;  margin:0 -15px; width:100%; }
    .table-display .row, .table-display .form-group{display:table-row;}
    .table-display [class*="col"]{float:none; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px;}
}
```

You would add the table-display class to your form:
     `<form class="form-horizontal table-display" role="form">`

HTH,
-Ted

Edited to add: heres a fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/eAaa3/
Of course you will need to stretch the frame to unstack it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and i used a table instead.
and if you implement it with a table, you can also use .table and .table-responsive classes of bootstrap.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I do with mine. I'm actually working with Bootstrap today

```
.control-label{
   float:left; 
   vertical-align:middle;        
}
```